# How do I get Xamarin.Forms CarouselPage in Android to scroll smoothly with many Images?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been working on optimizing my Xamarin.Forms app, and how my CarouselPage scrolls through images.  I've implemented logic to lazy-load only 3 images at a time (there could be 100s at some point in the carousel).

- **currentIndex** is the index of the page before the swipe.
- **WINDOW_SIZE** is a constant for how many images to load to the left and
  right of the current page.
- **CustomContent** is the ContentPage class that fills the carousel.
- **layout** is a private RelativeLayout inside the CustomContent
  ContentPage that gets built in the constructor.

Here is the code that is called on my OnCurrentPageChanged() event of my Carousel:

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged ()
{
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
        int newIndex = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);

        if (newIndex > currentIndex) 
        {
                currentIndex++;
                UnloadImages();
                LoadImages();
        }
        else if (newIndex < currentIndex)
        {
                currentIndex--;
                UnloadImages();
                LoadImages();
        }
}
```

Here are the functions that are being called:

```
private void LoadImages ()
{
        int lowIndex = currentIndex - WINDOW_SIZE >= 0 ? currentIndex - WINDOW_SIZE : 0;
        int highIndex = currentIndex + WINDOW_SIZE <= this.Children.Count() - 1 ? currentIndex + WINDOW_SIZE : this.Children.Count() - 1;

        for (int i = lowIndex; i <= highIndex; i++)
        {
                CustomContent custom = (CustomContent) this.Children[i];
                custom.LoadImage();
        }
}

private void UnloadImages ()
{
        int lowIndex = currentIndex - WINDOW_SIZE >= 0 ? currentIndex - WINDOW_SIZE : 0;
        int highIndex = currentIndex + WINDOW_SIZE <= this.Children.Count () - 1 ? currentIndex + WINDOW_SIZE : this.Children.Count () - 1;

        if (lowIndex - 1 >= 0) 
        {
                CustomContent custom = (CustomContent) this.Children[lowIndex - 1];
                custom.UnloadImage();
        }

        if (highIndex + 1 <= thoughts.Count () - 1) 
        {
                CustomContent thought = (CustomContent) this.Children[highIndex + 1];
                custom.UnloadImage();
        }
}
```

And this is the code that is called in the (CustomContent) ContentPages that fill the Carousel:

```
public void LoadImage ()
{
        this.Content = layout;
}

public void UnloadImage ()
{
        this.Content = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So... Images are problematic as they are not automatically disposed of.

My suggestion is to provide a custom renderer for ImageView that detects when it's containing ContentPage appears and disappears and loads / disposes of the image as appropriate.

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't think of custom renderers.  I will take a look, try it out, and let you know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code works very well with few minor issues. Sometimes, OnCurrentPageChanged does not get called on fast swiping and currentIndex gets out of sync. To correct this I changed currentIndex:

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged () {
    base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
    int newIndex = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
    //Set currentIndex, no need to use increment,decrement
    currentIndex = newIndex;
    UnloadImages();
    LoadImages();
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes, of course.  That is a better way to write that for sure.  The problem I am still running into is that the performance isnt that great.  When swiping, it is smooth, but when I let go it has some jitter.  Have you noticed this?

Comment: Hm I haven't noticed that. Could it be because of unloadImages function firing to early in that case, try to add small delay there maybe, not sure what can it be. Or maybe your ContentPages are more complex.